# How can i use Searching in sub category with category with out going to database each time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

In my form there are two comboboxes: one is category and another is sub category. Subcategory will load according to the category selected. Each subcategory have over 100 000 rows of data. How can I use Searching in sub category with category with out going to database each time?

I am using c# asp.net and SQL server.

Comment: Provide what you tried..?\

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `categories` and `sub categories` aren't changing all the time, you *could* cache them and update them periodically. This would allow your application to hit the cache instead of making a DB call each time.